# How difficult would it have been for a European to obtain access to US scientific journals in 1945?

Tags: 20th-century, europe, science, 1940s

On May 1, 1945, volume 158 of the Journal of Biologic Chemistry was published.
I'd like to establish to what degree –and how soon thereafter– its content may have been accessible in continental Europe (where Hitler had just committed suicide the previous day).

What would be the preconditions (economic, educational, demographic etc.) for a fictional European of the time to gain access to this type of scientific publications from the US?

Comment: You ask about availability "at the time", do you literally mean May 1945 or in some broader period?

Comment: @SteveBird, thanks for the comment. I did my best to disambiguate my question.

Comment: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=10&q=%22postwar+reconstruction%22+science+in+europe&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5

Comment: The following is a bit anecdotal: I was at [Technische Universität Berlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_University_of_Berlin), which (re)opened with support of the British commandant in April 1946. I can confirm from library signatures I have seen that international periodicals started to be aquired again immediately thereafter. I suppose this was with direct help from and under control of the British, who took an active role in establishing the university as a place of democratic education. The Berlin blockade made things complicated again in 1948, obviously.

Comment: Sweden or Switzerland May have received a small number in the mail. Low priority so unlikely to fly it, so on a slow ship.

Comment: The Geneva convention on treatment of POWs required all signatories to maintain a postal service to and from POWs - though the quantity of outgoing mail from POWs could be throttled. This was handled by neutral counties, often Portugal and Spain in the case of WW2. The additional burden of paying for postage thrice - once to Thomas Cook's London office; then courier to Thomas Cook's Lisbon office; and finally on to destination - undoubtedly reduced volume but didn't eliminate it.

Comment: Family lore asserts that my father and 3 others -  two of them Mexican tennis-exchange students trapped by the war - escaped near Arnhem in fall 1943 from a slave-labour march into Germany. When my father was finally smuggled back into Schiedam several months later, there was a blank postcard from Mexico City waiting for him.

Comment: probably no more difficult than a few years later. Main problems being a) knowing what's there, b) knowing who to contact to get a copy, c) paying for it, and d) waiting potentially weeks or months for shipping

Comment: I think there would be a substantial difference between neutrals, those occupied by the Western allies, and those occupied by the Soviets.